# Not getting updated record: Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am using `EntityManger.persist(Object)` to save the data in DB.
Then I am updating record just by setting the object property. i.e `Object.setProperty()` that will update the property in DB.
Now again if I select query for this `Object` am getting the old `Object` not the updated `Object`.

Please suggest.

Comment: You need to merge your object after editing it.

Comment: @Chafik But in DB I can see the changes after Object.setProperty() i.e without calling to merge(). problem is if via code i try getting this object i get the old one not updates.

Comment: Make sure that the object is still attached.

Comment: Show us your code. We can't find a bug without seeing the code.

Comment: Object is attached. am getting it by DB only using findById() and setting its property.

Answer (score 0):

The specific answer here depends a bit on your context, but in general:

When you do a `em.persist()` on an object, or retrieve an object from the database, this object will be what is called `managed` by `Hibernate`. This means that `Hibernate` will keep track of the objects state, and any changes made to the object inside a `transaction` will be automatically persisted when the `transaction` is `committed` (depending a bit on your `flush mode` settings).

A `managed` object can have a lifespan that is longer than the `transaction`, which means that the `transaction` is completed, but the object is still referenced, and can still change. What happens then is that the object becomes `detached`, which basically means that `Hibernate` no longer automatically keeps track of its state. Any changed done to a `detached` object will need to be explicitly reintroduced to `Hibernate`, in order to make the object `managed` again, and for the values of the object to be stored in the database.

What is happening here is that you are making changes to a `detached` object, and still expecting it to behave as a `managed` object. The solution is to either rework your transaction so that all your changes occur within the transaction (and thus on a `managed` object, not a `detached`), or to reintroduce the `detached` object by calling `em.merge()` with it as parameter. The `merge`-method does not actually make the object that is passed in `managed` (it remains `detached`), instead it returns the `managed` object corresponding to the `detached` object that was input as a parameter.

Comment: am making changes to attched object only. I am geting the object from DB by findById() and then setting its property by setters. and even I can see the chnages in DB table too which I set by setter method. But when i again do findById() the new retrived object contains old values only not the one which i set by setter method.

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing some code, but this seems to be quite impossible. The only reason I can think of for Hibernate to return different values than lies in the database is when the database is updated directly, leading to a mismatch between Hibernates cache and the db.